# Header Element Giving unwanted space

Tags: html, css, css-grid

This is driving me crazy!

It's not the padding or margin.

I tried to use overflow: hidden and setting a height, but overflow: hidden dose nothing and setting a height breaks my layout.

any help would be great thank you.

here is the site
https://www.myccandbuilds.com/

And the space between the header and the Black background div is what I'm talking about.

Comment: change line-height in header

Comment: Please create a [mcve] demonstrating your problem, otherwise your question is off topic for SO.  See [something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be being caused by line height. The issue also goes away with "line-height: 0;", meaning that there's possibly some empty text (newline, whitespace) in your element that's taking up space after the image.

Comment: yea set static height is bad because they also depend on screen size

Comment: you desided to try static linehehit ? check my answer, and you could avoid it

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by display property on the header, try `display: flex;` instead of `display: block;`.
it should fix this problem.